# Как правильно: "есть раков" или "есть раки"?

Tags: орфография, стилистика

Здравствуйте! Недавно встретила выражение "есть (в смысле "кушать") раки". Очень удивилась. Неужели это правильно?

Answer (score 3):

Можно "есть раков" и "есть раки".
Разница примерно та же, что и между "есть рыб" и "есть рыбу".
"Есть раков" - конкретных, штучно. "Есть (кушать) раки" - как блюдо.
Раки, крабы, креветки и т.п. как собирательное (т.е. как кушанье) теряют одушевлённость.
"Есть креветок", кстати, мало кто сейчас скажет.
Герои Брыльской и Мягкова, имхо, вполне правильно употребляют слово. "Салат из крабов", но "любить крабы". "Любить крабов" - это разводить их, содержать... Коли кушать - то крабы.

И ещё один подобный случай потери одушевлённости: выйти в люди, метить в министры, забрить в солдаты. У, казалось бы, одушевлённых существительных винительный падеж имеет форму неодушевлённого. Зализняк, правда, считает этот падеж особым, вторым винительным, но сути дела это не меняет.

Comment: Почему тогда по этой логике не скажешь: Я ем рак, я ем омар (если это одна штука)? Но говоришь: я ем бутерброд. Один рак или омар тоже может быть неодушевленным и рассматриваться как блюдо.

Comment: @Константин По какой "этой" логике? *Один рак или омар тоже может быть неодушевленным* - можете подтвердить?  Один рак может быть неодушевлен только когда  он, Рак,  - созвездие. Колебание в неодушевленности начинаются именно тогда, когда их перестают рассматривать как счетное множество, когда онит превращаются в массу.

Answer (score 3):

Раки, как и кальмары, могут быть как одушевленными, так и неодушевленными - чем ближе они к готовому блюду, тем их одушевленность "уменьшается".

Ловим мы раков, варим и чаще едим также раков, но в то же время уже начинаем любить раки под соусом. И фаршируем обычно не кальмаров, а кальмары.

Answer (score 2):

Вы резонно удивились: конечно же, это ошибка. РАК - существительное одушевленное, поэтому форма вин. пад. множ. числа у него омонимична форме род. пад. множ. числа: РАКОВ. Те, кто употребляют форму вин. пад. множ. числа, омонимичную форме именит. пад. множ. числа (РАКИ), вероятно, считают это существительное неодушевленным, что не соответствует языковой норме. Кстати, словарь Кузнецова в качестве одного из примеров употребления этого слова дает сочетание "ловить раков".

Comment: Да, но, тем не менее, говорят "есть крабы". Вспомните из "Иронии судьбы": "Но ты ведь и салат из крабов уже приготовила. А я так люблю крабы!"  
Хотя, возможно, тут речь идет, скорее, о консервах, что, само собой, не может быть одушевленным предметом.

Comment: Интересное наблюдение. Я думаю, вы правы. Словарь Кузнецова даёт это как отдельное значение (только формы множественного числа). Вообще, в русском языке есть целая группа полисемичных слов, употребляемых обычно как одушевленные, которые в одном из значений могут использоваться как неодушевленные, и наоборот.