# Морские звезды или морских звезд

Tags: грамматика

Подскажите, будьте добры, сочетание «морские звезды» (одуш.) будет ли приобретать иную форму в винительном падеже?
На берег выбросило морские звезды (морских звезд).

Answer (score 1):

Слово `звезда` склоняется разным образом в зависимости от того, обозначает оно одушевленный или неодушевленный предмет.

Винительный падеж множественного числа совпадает с формой именительного для неодушевленных существительных и с формой родительного для одушевленных. А прилагательное `морской` вынуждено согласовываться с существительным.

То есть:

- `звёзды` соответствует неодушевленным звёздам: символам, небесным телам (*вижу звёзды на погонах*, *изучаю далёкие звёзды*);
- `звёзд` соответствует одушевленным звёздам: знаменитостям, морским звёздам (*вижу звёзд эстрады*, *изучаю морских звёзд*).

Answer (score 1):

Учебники пишут:

> Колеблющиеся признаки  одушевлённости / неодушевлённости   имеют
> существительные, называющие микроорганизмы (вирус, фаг, бактерия,
> микроб), а также некоторых беспозвоночных (личинка, устрица, моллюск,
> полип и др.).

**Морские звёзды** как раз относятся к "и др." беспозвоночным.

Пару примеров из Нацкорпуса для наглядности:

> Но и в такую погоду Тынэна ходила по берегу моря, **подбирала**
> выброшенные водой водоросли, **морские звезды**, обкатанные до
> глянцевой черноты осколки моржовых клыков, раковины и все смотрела в
> белую от волн морскую даль. (Юрий Рытхэу)
>
> С помощью батископа можно изучать морское дно, **искать** ракушки и
> **морских звезд**, предупреждать аквалангистов о появлении акул и о других подводных опасностях, обнаруживать косяки рыб. (Журнал "Техника молодёжи", 1976)

Answer (score 1):

***На берег выбросило морских звезд.***

В данном предложении я бы предпочел скорее "одушевленный" вариант, хотя тут еще и контекст важен.

grizzly совершенно прав, относя "морских звезд" *к группе существительных с колеблющейся категорией одушевленности (во множественном числе)*. Это означает, что ни один из вариантов не будет грамматической ошибкой, что и подтверждают его примеры.

Однако вопрос-то не снимается. Ч*ем должен руководствоваться автор, выбирая одну из двух допустимых форм?* Ответ есть; хотя я не нашел его в авторитетных источниках, поэтому можете считать моим личным мнением.

Если данный объект ("звезды" в нашем случае) рассматриваются как отдельные организмы, то предпочтительнее именно одушевленный вариант. Если же объект просто масса , сырье или что-то подобное, то причин для одушевленности гораздо меньше.
Сразу оговорюсь, что мой совет может показаться противоречащим примеру из Рытхеу, но там, во-первых, речь идет о давно погибших, превратившихся в массу, а во-вторых, накладывается особый национально-бытовой колорит: Для чукоткой девочки наши представления об одушевленности не слишком актуальны.

Чтобы окончательно разобраться со своим отношением к объекту воспользуйтесь простым индикатором: словом "люблю". Помните в "Иронии судьбы" герой Мягкова уверял зрителей, что он очень "любит крабы"?! Это вызвало в своё время массу обсуждений со сломанными копьями, а ведь он совершенно прав. *"Я люблю крабы"* означает, что он любит их есть. лишенных не просто одушевленности, но и всякой индивидуальности, штучности...
А вот "Я люблю крабов" означало бы, что говорящий испытывает нежные чувства к ним как к организмам. Разводить их, любоваться... Что там еще с ними можно делать?

Короче, представьте себе именно этих, выброшенных на берег, морских звезд. ***Вы (допустим) любите "морских звезд"  или "морские звезды"***? Уверен, что предпочтете первый вариант. Ну а если второй, значит для вас они - масса, просто покрывшая берег, и тогда неодушевленный вариант вполне правилен по тому смыслу, который вы вкладываете.

(++) ===

Загляните еще сюда
[Правильное употребление](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/40211)
и сюда
[Как правильно: "есть раков" или "есть раки"?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/1060)

В принципе там всё разъяснено на других примерах, но наш случай сильно осложнен многозначностью слова "звезда", хотя на самом деле эта многозначность по сути ни на что не влияет, крорме понимания.